# If position is fundamentally undefined at quantum scales, how can strings be Planck length?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, spacetime, string-theory, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

From how I understand Quantum Mechanics and the Uncertainty Principle, quantum objects position is fundamentally undefined. So how could an object like a string with a clearly defined geometry exist that has a length around the Planck length? It should be smeared in space larger than a Planck length instead. There should be no meaning in saying any object has a length equal to or around a Planck length. Is my understanding of the Uncertainty Principle flawed?

Comment: Who says that the string length is the Planck length? Who says that strings have perfectly well defined lengths?

Comment: @Javier I didn't think it would be something controversial so I just did a quick Google search and found this https://www.pbs.org/wgbh/nova/physics/sense-of-scale-string-theory.html

Comment: @Javier [for your second question]  ..so they aren't literal strings that vibrate? I suppose I just unconsciously assumed if strings vibrate they will have to have some defined size and shape. With electrons you just have some properties of one point so no problem you can smear that out, but with strings I would assume that the whole string is needed to perform the vibration, it collectively has the property not just one point. So how will you smear without losing the property?

Comment: String theory claims dimensions are compactified on a length scale a fair bit larger than the Planck length, in a manner that addresses certain hierarchy problems. We should expect strings to not be exactly a Planck length either, especially when you bear in mind Lorentz transformations.

Comment: @J.G. To be clear, do I correctly assume then that the claim made in the link I shared in the previous comment is, in your belief, incorrect?

Comment: @J.G. even if they're not exactly a Planck length would their geometry be clearly defined?

Comment: You should revise your understanding of the Uncertainty principle. It does not say that position is undefined. It says that the spread ofits possible values is not independent of the spread of the possible values of momentum.

Comment: @l1mbo Short answer: The strings of string theory are quantum strings. You can think of them as "classical curves" only before quantization. After quantization, all the observables, such as the positions along the strings, become non-commutative operators subject to usual uncertainty principles of quantum mechanics satisfying some extra constraints that in the classical limit correspond to the equations of motion of the string.